# Correlation of g and Honesty, Rationality, etc?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, personality, intelligence, bias, correlation

Are there any meta-analyses reporting the correlations of g (IQ, general mental ability) with:

1. Honesty-Humility (e.g. in HEXACO model). 
   I know Conscientiousness (of Big Five) generally has zero correlation with IQ.
2. Critical thinking, rationality, thinking biases.
3. Wisdom. As operationalized by researchers like Judith Glück. There are several scales for measuring Wisdom such as the Berlin model.

Comment: Could you please provide references to frame your understanding of the concepts listed in items `2.` and `3.`?

Comment: Sorry, just saw your comment Seanny123. Can you please elaborate what you mean, I didn't really understand. Thanks.

Comment: I meant, what definitions are you using for "critical thinking, wisdom... Etc"? Are these definitions based on prior research or just personal experience?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I was referring to these as constructs as defined in research. For example, Wisdom is operationalized by several researchers. Judith Glück is one. There are several scales for measuring Wisdom such as the Berlin model.

Comment: Could you please add these references to your original question to make it easier for someone to answer it?

Comment: [Stanovich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_Stanovich) has written about Intelligence and Rationality. However, his own (PC) summaries seem to contradict his studies' findings so relying on these summaries may not be a good idea.